# setting timeout for a long running WCF Service

Tags: timeout, wcf

I have a WCF service method which takes more than two hours to execute (runs some reports). how can I make sure that it doesn't timeout regardless of the time it takes? I think there are many timeout settings in WCF config, I am not sure which one is relevant for me. for ASMX webservices, there was an option to specify infinite timeout setting, is there a similar one for WCF?. also do I need to alter any IIS settings for this (WCF servcie is hosted in IIS), like recycling of worker processes, idle timeouts etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using callbacks? Your client sends a request and then waits for a notification from the server for when it is done? This would probably require a change in the client, but in that way, your service can "rattle the chain" and tell the client when the report is finished.

help: http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx

WCF timeouts:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/

You should also consider the timeouts on the client side, as well. (binding.OpenTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, CloseTimeout etc.)

Another option would be to host the WCF in a Windows Service, which could simplify your situation, as it removes IIS from the equation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Or,  what about using a one way WCF call? That way, the call will return to the client ASAP after sending the request.

[Need sample fire and forget async call to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774648/need-sample-fire-and-forget-async-call-to-wcf-service)

Comment: yes, I am trying to host the WCF service in Windows service, I think callback is not appropriate in this scenario because it is a long running task and user can't be expected to wait for such a long time to get the notification of the result. it is a fire and forget call and user will just check the file system on the network to see if the reports have been created or not. Initially I was against to using Windows service because of the hassle of installing and uninstalling and so I tried using IIS, but it is causing timeout issues.

Comment: What about using a one way call in WCF? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774648/need-sample-fire-and-forget-async-call-to-wcf-service

Answer (score 8):

This is an abuse of web services. Don't do this.

Instead, have the web service kick off the long-running operation, running in a separate process. If the clients need to know when the reports are done, then have the "separate process" keep track of the report creation and have it note when the reports are finished. The client can call a web service to check that status.

You really don't want to be depending on an HTTP connection remaining open for hours. It's a network. Things happen on networks. Bad things.

Comment: yes, I think you are right, I am trying to host WCF service in a windows service to see if that solves the timeout issue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a [WCF workflow service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646977.aspx) (using WF) instead. These are specifically designed to handle long-running processes, especially if you use persistence.

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is not a workflow, it is simply a task that takes long time to execute, so using WF might be an overkill for this.