# Calling WCF operation that has no return value asynchronously

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have a long running operation:

```
void LongRunningOperation(string someValue);
```

How do i call it asynchronously (I want a fire and forget mechanism)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774648/need-sample-fire-and-forget-async-call-to-wcf-service?

Comment: To clarify: Can I omit setting up the delegate to: CallLongRunningOperationCompleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set the mode to oneway.

you do not require to call these methods asynchronously. call to the methods returns as soon as they are call if the mode is one way.

use:

`[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]`   attribute to describe your operation contract.

Comment: Not quite - while this will work just fine, it does **not** return control to the caller right away. The call will block (wait) until the service that will deal with the call has received the message. When you want a call to return immediately (not waiting for the service to respond), you need to call it asynchronously.

Comment: Actually, it is dependent on various things, mainly the transport protocol and more regarding the channel shape and binding elements – reliable session / one way binding element. Moreover, it is even affected by the InstanceContextMode which is set on your service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already configured your proxy to the service, you will need to do the following (in VS):

1. Open your project that references the service, then go to service references.
2. Right-click the relevant service reference and select 'Configure Service Reference' from the context menu.
3. Tick the box that says 'Generate asynchronous operations'
4. After your client code regenerates, you will see a method that says `BeginLongRunningOperation`; that's your async method.