# Calling Async WCF service at Application_Exit

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, silverlight, asynchronous

I have the following code..

```
 Private Sub Application_Exit(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Exit
        If MainPage.ModeOfOperation = "PROPOSALMODIFICATION" Then

            MainPage.InitializeServiceEndPoint(client.Endpoint)
            MessageBox.Show("This is a test")
            client.FlagQuotationWithUserAsync(MainPage.FetchQuotationNo, MainPage.FetchReferenceNo, "F", "", "", "")



        End If

    End Sub
```

But it doesnot work as I think Async calls are not allowed at the time of the application exit.

I have also done the following

1. Converting the Async method to sync by the following code in the WCF service :

OperationContract(AsyncPattern:=False)

and then calling it from the xaml like

```
client.SR_IService1_BeginFlagQuotationWithUser(FetchQuotationNo, ID, "T", UserRole, ProdCode, UserID, Nothing, Nothing)
```

But still the function is not being called at the time of the Application exit.

**PLEASE NOTE : The main problem is that I want to do something at the time of the application close/exit and I have to call a WCF webservice. Please help I have no clue now..**

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider to change your method call to sync but "one way".

Afterthis, i'd call it from aplication_exit code behind method.

I think in this case your app still "exists" (until method execution not done).

Take a look on this simple post for short example: [Need sample fire and forget async call to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774648/need-sample-fire-and-forget-async-call-to-wcf-service)

This solution may also help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/564450/CallingplusintoplusyourplusdatabaseplusonplusSilve

Comment: can you help me with the code for the one way ? Something like this OperationContract(AsyncPattern:=False Oneway:=true). Please let me know.

Comment: No it is not working. As I have mentioned in the question that it is working when I am calling it in the page load or in other place but When I am using it in the application_exit or UserControl_lostfocus then it is not working. do you have a work around ?

Comment: updated - see also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/564450/CallingplusintoplusyourplusdatabaseplusonplusSilve

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to accomplish. Unfortunately, while the application is exiting, you may run into issues trying to do it the way you are doing. This is because you have a proxy to the service reference and there is a whole bunch of things that go on behind the scenes you need to understand. Also, if the reason the application is shutting down is because of a System.ServiceModel exception, it's almost guaranteed you will not be able to make this type of call. It's also not best practice. **Instead, just use REST.** This will work 100%