# What do I need to do to prevent a client waiting on a long WCF service method?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, import, bulk

I am writing a WCF webservice that includes a method that accepts an array of objects and inserts them into the database. This could take a long time, so I can't just expect the client to wait.

My colleague thinks that I don't need to do anything, that it's the client's job to call my service asynchronously. I just write a normal method. This doesn't sound right to me, although I hope it's true because looking at WCF async tutorials and SO questions has just confused me so far.

Is he correct? If not, how do I actually write the method in a way that would allow the client to call the method asynchronously or otherwise avoid hanging?

If he is correct (as appears to be the case), then what is the point of defining an asynchronous method ([OperationContract (AsyncPattern=true)], Begin, End, etc.). Is it a way explicitly handling asynchronous calls, or allowing interactivity, or what?

Comment: Your client is correct. There's nothing special to do in the service.

Comment: Yep colleague is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* fall on the client's side. They are the ones that have to prevent their app/UI from hanging.

Have your client call your method asynchronously. If they are using a service reference, all methods/events are generated automatically.

```
myWcfClient.myMethodCompleted 
          += new EventHandler<myMethodCompletedEventArgs>(myCallBack);
myWcfClient.myMethodAsync(args);


public void myCallback(object sender, myMethodCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  var myResult = e.Result;

}
```

Comment: So what is AsyncPattern for then? More complicated interaction than a simple import requires?

Comment: If they are generating the service reference in Visual Studio, those methods will already be auto generated.

Comment: @Drew the AsyncPattern is so you can return Tasks / precursor to Tasks from WCF, something you shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 1):

If your client doesn't care what happens with the service call, you want a simple fire and forget operation and you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774648/need-sample-fire-and-forget-async-call-to-wcf-service).

The AsyncPattern property tells the runtime that your operations implement the .NET Framework asynchronous method design pattern. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.asyncpattern(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want your client application to know what has happened with your service call then you can use this pattern. There are other ways to get the results though.

Answer (score -1):

This is only on the client side, I've skipped the old event driven async bleh pattern and replaced it with the async-await pattern. Not waiting for webmethod calls async, and blocking the UI... doesn't even belong in this century ;)

If you are using .net 4.5+ you are getting the async-await pattern for free (Unless wp8, where you still have to wrap it). The async methods should already be avaliable through the service. I recommend the [AsyncBridge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge/) if you are using old frameworks, which allows you to use the async-await pattern for cases like this. The alternative is to stick to the old event driven async nightmare. The examples below is **only possible if you are using C#5.0 or never**.

Ensure to start in a new thread from a non async method.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(client.DoSomethingAsync("blabla") ).ContinueWith(...);
```

The last part is run after your method has completed, check for exceptions to completion code etc.

Or in some async method

```
public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync(String text) {
   // Exception handling etc
   return await client.DoSomethingAsync(text);
}
```

wrapping APM to async-await pattern:

```
public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper 
{
    readonly YourServiceClient client;
    public ServiceWrapper(YourServiceClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync(string someParameter)
    {
        return await Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginDoSomeStuff, client.EndDoSomeStuff, someParameter, new object());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Opening and closing connections in a wrapped service. (I don't have my devbox avaliable right now but this should work).

```
public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper 
{
    EndpointAddress address;
    public ServiceWrapper(EndpointAddress clientAddress)
    {
         address = clientAddress;
    }

    public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync(string someParameter)
    {
        // handle exceptions etc here, can be done some cleaner..
        var client = new YourServiceClient();
        client.Endpoint.Address = address.Address; // can skip this..
        await client.OpenAsync()
        var res =  await Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginDoSomeStuff, client.EndDoSomeStuff, someParameter, new object());
        await client.CloseAsync();
        return res;
    }
}
```

One last thing I'm not sure how you generate your proxy, if you are using vs make sure to hook of the checkbox allowing async methods when configuring the service. If you are using svcutil add the appropriate flags.

[Async-await pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

[Old event driven async pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751505(v=vs.100).aspx)

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: I started going with something like this, but my boss said this approach would keep the connection open the whole time and they didn't want that. Is this true?

Comment: @DrewS No that's false! Well the code above will do that I will modify it to connect each time. You just open the connection, await the wcf call then close the connection. I didn't add it for simplicity.

Comment: @DrewS I modified the code for you now, if you look at the last part. Here i open and close a connection, each time I perform a wcf call. Didn't have time to cover error handling, but there is plenty of info to go around. the post is long to ;)

Comment: This code is just bad. Communication exceptions now leak as unobserved exceptions, StartNew shouldn't be used http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html and neither should ContinueWith http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html